# TypeScript lint or config option to disable implicit union types T | Promise<T> in async methods

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have found that I repeatedly do the same error by forgetting to add `await` in `async` TypeScript code in the following pattern of checking cached variable and requesting it from an `async` method. The problem is that I am working with gradually typed libraries and could pass returned union types to untyped APIs without design-time errors.

```
public async sample() {
    let address = this.address || this.getAddressAsync();
    let valid = <boolean>this.untypedUtil.validateAddress(address);
    return valid;
}
```

`getAddressAsync` returns `Primise<string>` while the `this.address` is `string`. The variable becomes `string | Primise<string>`, but `this.untypedUtil.validateAddress` is from JS and doesn't care. Adding type annotations manually seems to defeat the initial vision of TS gradual non-intrusive types, and many linters already do nice job of protecting me from my stupid mistakes.

It seems reasonable that if I am inside an `async` method I usually do not want this to happen for `T | Promise<T>` for any `T` and I would like a linter rule to have a warning for this.

Googled but cannot find it. Does such rule/config exists already?

Comment: There are some outstanding issues for typescript asking for an error to be generated if you call an async function from inside an async function without using `await` or otherwise making clear what you mean. e.g. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13376

If that ever gets resolved it might help you (but as it isn't resolved yet this is just a comment not an answer).